# vba shell command unexpectedly terminates excel with no error message

Tags: vba, excel, shell, batch-file

I had a vba macro that previously launched a .bat batch file using the shell command.

The form of shell command used was very simple (as shown):

```
dblResult = Shell("c:\fullPath\batchFile.bat")
```

All of a sudden this has stopped working, with the excel application closing unexpectedly at this line of code, without error or warning message and before the command window opens for the batch file to begin executing its DOS commands.

The batch files will still run successfully if launched manually rather than from the excel VBA macro.

This ran on a corporate workstation so I'm wondering if there may have been any system changes made by security updates that now prevent what might be perceived as a risky behavior from an application.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Addendum 2017-09-06 :

The fault with VBA shell command closing/crashing excel was first noticed just after 10th July and was found to be also manifest across other Windows 7 machines in the business.

Today a corporate Windows 7 laptop, which when previously tested was found to have the same issue has now since (mysteriously) reverted back to the Shell command working again.

The only difference between the laptop for which the shell command is functioning and the desktop where it crashes the Excel application is a Windows Security update KB3203468 which was automatically installed on the (working) laptop 25th July, which I believe post-dates the time when the laptop was first tested and found to display the same problematic behavior.

At the moment this is the only lead towards solving this, and the description on the update given refers to

"A security vulnerability exists in Microsoft Office 2010 32-Bit Edition that could allow arbitrary code to run when a maliciously modified file is opened. This update resolves that vulnerability."

which seems to be in the right ball park of what is being affected, namely VBA for applications.

Interestingly the published issue date of the update is 11th July coinciding with the problem first occurring, even while it appears to have been responsible for resolving the issue on the laptop.

Unfortunately any attempt to install this update on the desktop (as administrator) to verify if this resolves the problem closes with message 'There are no products affected by this package installed on this system' and so it fails to install.

A corporate IT guy is looking into it....

Answer (score 0):

Lots of Excel VBA applications are stopping working due to a recent update. It's now case sensitive. Check the case of the actual path / file name.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: I cut and pasted the path name from windows explorer and double checked the filename and all character cases match.  If a typo is purposefully inserted into the path, then a normal path / file not found error occurs and break mode entered rather than crashing the excel application.

Comment: Ideally it would be nice to have the code to test with if you're able to post this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Symantec anti-virus by any chance? I had this exact same problem where Excel would be unexpectedly closed when trying to execute a .bat file, and it was due to Symantec killing the process.